# Zend Framework configuring decorator

Tags: zend-framework, forms, decorator

```
if(count($this->form->email->getMessages()) > 0)
                        {
                            $e = '<ul>';
                                $m = $this->form->email->getMessages();
                                foreach($m as $me)
                                {
                                    $e .= '<li>';
                                        $e .= $me;
                                    $e .= '</li>';
                                }
                            $e .= '</ul>';                          
                            echo $e;
                            unset($e);
                            unset($m);
                        }
```

I'm currenly passing form object to VIEW and echo every elemen manually.

But when comes to errors, it takes a lot of code to write.

Could someone tell, how to output errors for each element without such amount of code?

Thanks!

Here is the picture of all decorators before the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found amazing method:

renderFormErrors();

Just what i was looking for. :)

But for individual outputing, can be used decorator. Found on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible since to havent provided your current decorator. However, you should add the helper

> Errors

to the decorator.

Comment: Just a second, i will post a picture.

Comment: Yea helper is one way. :)

Passing it an object of current element and returning already generated list of errors in needed wrapper.

But question is still open. How to output them already generated by zend decorator.